# MySQL: Getting "busiest" or "most popular" hour from a datetime field?

Tags: mysql, datetime, count, popularity

Consider the following table which has the fields - id (int) and date_created (datetime):

```
id       date_created

 1       2010-02-25 12:25:32
 2       2010-02-26 13:40:37
 3       2010-03-01 12:02:22
 4       2010-03-01 12:10:23
 5       2010-03-02 10:10:09
 6       2010-03-03 12:45:03
```

I want to know the busiest/most popular hour of the day for this set of data. In this example, the result I'm looking for would be 12.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like both Simon and Peter's answers, but I can't select both as accepted. I combined the 2 to make a cleaner query that only returned the popular hour (I don't need the counts).

```
SELECT hour(date_created) AS h 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY h 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 7):

To get just the most popular hour, use this query

```
select date_format( date_created, '%H' ) as `hour`
  from [Table]
 group by date_format( date_created, '%H' )
 order by count(*) desc
 limit 1;
```

If you want to look at all the data, go with this one

```
select count(*) as num_records
     , date_created
     , date_format( date_created, '%H' ) as `hour`
  from [Table]
 group by `hour`
 order by num_records desc;
```

Comment: Any advantage of using date_format() over hour()  or vice-versa?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  It was just the function I was already familiar with off the top of my head.

Comment: That's the same reason I used hour().

Answer (score 4):

If you want something a little more flexible, perhaps to the half hour, or quarter hour, you can do the following:

```
SELECT floor(time_to_sec(date_created)/3600),count(*) AS period 
FROM table GROUP BY period ORDER BY c DESC
```

If you want the most popular 2 hour interval, use 7200. The most popular 15 minute interval, use 900. You just need to remember you are dealing with seconds (3600 seconds in an hour).

Comment: This throws an error because interval is a comparison function ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_interval ). 

Changing the word interval to foo works, but the results are not correct.

Comment: of course, forget about interval. I left off the count, so it couldn't order it correctly (whoops).

Comment: @k00k: The error in the query above is very simple. The second selection `COUNT(*)` has two aliases, which is a problem. Move the alias 'period' to the first selected field, so one has 'c' and one has 'period'.

Comment: @BrentBaisley, your COUNT(*) has two aliases by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `hour()` function to extract the hour, then do the usual aggregation:

`SELECT count(hour(date_created)) AS c, hour(date_created) AS h FROM table GROUP BY h ORDER BY c DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H') as hours, 
  count(*) as count 
FROM 
  myTable 
GROUP BY 
  hours 
ORDER BY 
  count DESC
```